# Conditional setuptools entry_points

Tags: python, setuptools, entry-point

Is it possible to have conditional entry_points defined in setup.py? I noticed that it is possible to *tag* an entry point using `extras`, but that entry point will be available even if the package is installed without that extra feature.

```
setup(name='my.package',
      ...
      extras_require={
          'special': [
              'dependency1',
              'dependency2',
          ],
      },
      ...
      entry_points="""
      [custom_entrypoint]
      handlername = my.package.special:feature [special]
      """,
  )
```

It appears as that `custom_entrypoint` is available even if the package is installed without that `special` feature (`pip install my.package[special]`). Is there a simple way of getting something like this working?

Answer (score 2):

In your "plugin loader" (whatever happens to find the entry point, either by name or by enumerating the full set of available entry points for a given namespace) you need to do something like the following:

```
import pkg_resources

# Get a reference to an EntryPoint, somehow.
plug = pkg_resources.get_entry_info('pip', 'console_scripts', 'pip')

# This is sub-optimal because it raises on the first failure.
# Can't capture a full list of failed dependencies.
# plug.require()

# Instead, we find the individual dependencies.

failed = []

for extra in sorted(plug.extras):
    if extra not in plug.dist._dep_map:
        continue  # Not actually a valid extras_require dependency?

    for requirement in i.dist._dep_map[extra]:
        try:
            pkg_resources.require(str(requirement))
        except pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound:
            failed.append((plug.name, extra, str(requirement)))
```

And there we go; for a given plugin you'll get a list of failed dependencies (or `not failed` in the event of success) listing the `entry_point` plugin name, `[foo]` extra tag, and specific unsatisfied package requirement.

An example of this in action comes from the [web.command](https://github.com/marrow/web.command) package's `web versions --namespace` sub-command.  Note how the `waitress` `extras_require` is satisfied, where the `gevent` one is explicitly specifying the `gevent` package is missing:

[image: Sample usage.]

Unfortunately I don't actually have a multiple-dependency `entry_point` example handy to show, and it's important to note that the package listed as "missing" might not always match up with the name of the `extras_require`.

Answer (score 1):

The entry points are written to `package.dist-info/entry_points.txt`. I was suggesting to see what packages are installed on the system in `setup.py`, but it probably wouldn't help here because the `dist-info` might be processed before the other packages are installed by `pip`; also later on, even if you installed the other packages, these entry points wouldn't magically show up unless you run `setup.py` for `my.package` with correct arguments.

I suggest you refactor so that there'd be one package named `my.package` and another installable package called `my.package.special`; the latter would have the `my.package`, `dependency1` and `dependency2` as dependencies, and the entry point. Now if you wanted to install `my.package` it would do so without the specials; `pip install my.package.special` to get the special feature on top of that.

Comment: I ended up with something similar. Instead of moving the functionality to a new package I kept it in the same. I didnt want to move the functionalities out of several packages into new special packages, because I use it as an `experimental` feature toggle. Instead I created a special package called `app.experimental` and included that as an extras_require within the other packages. When doing the iter_entry_points loops I checked that the entrypoint had fulfilled their requirements if not it was ignored (`entrypoint.require()` will raise `pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound`).

Comment: @Torkel then please do post your solution as an alternative answer and [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) :D

Comment: Creating whole Python packages to suit the "meta dependency" need is silly, when that's exactly what `extras_require` is for.